# Loop with lead or lag through a table to create a subscription serie in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a table with subscription series out of a table with separate subscriptions in T-SQL. A subscription series contains all the subscriptions of 1 relation_number that follow within 14 days (Difference between startdate of former subscription of the same relation is smaller than or equal to 14 days). The values in this column can for example comma separated.

I already created a column that indicates a switch_out (subscription within 14 days after this subscription) and switch_in (subscription within 14 days before this subscription) in the subscription dataset. However I did not succeed to create one of the last two columns of the table below. I thought about using a loop (with LEAD or LAG) for this, however I don't know how to do this. In the example below are only subscription series with a maximum length of two subscriptions, however this is just a simple example, subscription series with more for example 10 or 20 are also possible.

When I have one of these columns I could use these in combination with relation_number to group by to get the subscription series table, I would like to have.

Can someone help me to create one of these columns or does someone know a better way to create the table with subscription series?

`Subscription` table (last two columns do not exist yet):

| Relation_number | Subscription_number | Startdate | Stopdate | Switch_in | Switch_out | Subscription_serie | Subscription_serie2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1-1-2020 | 31-12-2020 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 1-1-2021 | 1-6-2021 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1-1-2022 |  |  |  | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 1-1-2019 | 31-12-2019 |  | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 1-1-2020 | 31-12-2020 | 1 |  | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 1-1-2021 | 1-6-2021 |  |  | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 1-1-2022 |  |  |  | 2 | 5 |

`Subscription` table I eventually would like to create:

| Relation_number | Subscription_serie |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3,5 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4,7 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the values of rows in a column with the `STRING_AGG` function, and to do this you must group the values by column or columns.

The answer to your question is to group the values by `(Relation_number, Subscription_serie)` and combine the values in the `Subscription_number` column with the stringaddd function

```
SELECT Relation_number,STRING_AGG(Subscription_number,',') AS Subscription_serie
FROM Test
GROUP BY Relation_number,Subscription_serie
ORDER BY Relation_number,Subscription_serie desc
```

for Subscription_serie2

```
 SELECT Relation_number,STRING_AGG(Subscription_number,',') AS Subscription_serie2
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY Relation_number,Subscription_serie2
    ORDER BY Relation_number,Subscription_serie2 desc
```

I fetched the following table with lag, lead, and any order other than this is almost impossible in my opinion.

```
select Relation_number,Subscription_serie,Subscription_serie2

from (select *,Lag(Subscription_serie,1) over(order by Relation_number) as prevcol1,Lag(Subscription_serie2,1) over(order by Relation_number) as prevcol2 from
(select *,
   case Switch_in when 1 then concat(prevcol,',',Subscription_number) else cast(row_number() over(partition by Relation_number order by Relation_number) as nvarchar) end as Subscription_serie,
   case Switch_out when 1 then concat(nextcol,',',Subscription_number) else cast(row_number() over(partition by Relation_number order by Relation_number) as nvarchar) end as Subscription_serie2
     from (select Relation_number,Subscription_number,Switch_in,Switch_out,Lag(Subscription_number,1) over(order by Relation_number) as prevcol,lead(Subscription_number,1) over(order by Relation_number) as nextcol
FROM Test) t) t) t
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. This is indeed the right step to take after having created one of the subscription_serie variables, however creating these is part of my question. Do you know how to create either subscription_serie or subscription_serie2?

Comment: In the event of both series, the order of your favorite table will fall to the ground, unless you fetch each one separately. I made changes in response. I hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this solution does not solve my problem. The subscription series cannot be longer than 2 subscriptions in your code.